# Issue with mysql_query INSERT (PHP 5.3) not adding to table

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, mysqli

I have an job application form that sends an email with the information, and should also insert the values from the form (the values of which are imported into the handler.php seen below at the top) into a table in a database on the server.

However, it's not inserting the values, and I can't figure out why.

I actually took this script from my client's old version of the website on a different domain and server, and it's still working perfectly on that one, so I can't figure out why it's not working here. The only thing I've changed is the database details. At one point I thought the issue might be because mysql_connect etc. is deprecated in favour of mysqli-equivalents, but the client's server is still running PHP 5.3, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Via PHPMyAdmin, I have a database, and a table called 'team'. I create all the columns according to the original setup on the old website, so that each item you see in the INSEERT query down below will have somewhere to go.

Am I missing something in my SQL connection code? The username, password, domain and database are all correct...

```
$date = date("d/M/Y");
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$dob = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['dob']));
$contact = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['contact']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$preferredCity = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['preferredCity']));
$nightsMo = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nightsMo']));
$nightsTu = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nightsTu']));
$nightsWe = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nightsWe']));
$nightsTh = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nightsTh']));
$nightsFr = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nightsFr']));
$nightsSa = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nightsSa']));
$nightsSu = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['nightsSu']));
$ownCar = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['ownCar']));
$previousWork = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['previousWork']));

if (Trim($nightsMo)=="") $nightsMo="NULL";
if (Trim($nightsTu)=="") $nightsTu="NULL";
if (Trim($nightsWe)=="") $nightsWe="NULL";
if (Trim($nightsTh)=="") $nightsTh="NULL";
if (Trim($nightsFr)=="") $nightsFr="NULL";
if (Trim($nightsSa)=="") $nightsSa="NULL";
if (Trim($nightsSu)=="") $nightsSu="NULL";
if (Trim($ownCar)=="") $ownCar="NULL";

$username="XXX";
$password="XXX";
$database="XXX";


mysql_connect("example.co.uk",$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


mysql_query("INSERT INTO team (t_date, t_name, t_dob, t_contact, t_email, t_preferredCity, t_nightsMo, t_nightsTu, t_nightsWe, t_nightsTh, t_nightsFr, t_nightsSa, t_nightsSu, t_ownCar, t_previousWork, t_picture) VALUES ('$date', '$name','$dob','$contact','$email','$preferredCity',$nightsMo,$nightsTu,$nightsWe,$nightsTh,$nightsFr,$nightsSa,$nightsSu,$ownCar,'$previousWork', '$filePath')");

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Are you getting any messages back? Have you looked at what the values are before you put them in the query?

Comment: a) mysql_* functions are deprecated.  Don't use them.  b) Aside from the single `or die()`, you're not doing any kind of error checking/recovery at all.  All the mysql calls you're making can potentially fail and will return FALSE if they do.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development. Might be missing quotes around some of your values.

Comment: `$filePath` isn't showing in your code. If it's not in use, then it's undefined and will break your query.

Comment: One text field with a `'` and your query breaks. Read up on sql injection and switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements.

Comment: I added @Fred-ii- 's error reporting code and discovered that the $nightsMo, $nightsTu (etc) fields weren't validating correctly, as they're tickboxes with a value of -1 set to them. I've just removed them and compressed them all into one simple textbox (as well as the conversions to NULL if they're empty section), as the checkboxes are unnecessary. So, I now replaced the INSERT statement to reflect this, with t_nights and '$nights' respectively. Still not working though :/

Comment: Make sure all your form's elements match in names. If one has a typo, or an upper or lower case letter, than that could do it too, a hyphen, space etc. Also check your column names and types. Curious though, your DB connection, it's not `mysqli_` by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what could be the cause, but refactored your code to streamline & simplify things so it’s easier to debug.

The first thing I did was take all of your `$_POST` checks into a structure that uses one main array (`$post_array`) and then rolls through that array to process the values & assign them to similarly named variables.

Additionally, I added a `$result` string check for the `mysql_query` which then does a check to see if that is even returned. And if it fails, show us what the error is via `mysql_error()`.  That should be the key to help you debug what is happening.

```
$date = date("d/M/Y");

// Set the post values array.
$post_array('name','dob','contact','email','preferredCity','nightsMo','nightsTu','nightsWe','nightsTh','nightsFr','nightsSa','nightsSu');

// Role through the post values array.
foreach($post_array as $post_key => $post_value) {
  $$post_key = isset($_POST[$post_key]) ? Trim(stripslashes($_POST[$post_key])) : null; 
}

$username="XXX";
$password="XXX";
$database="XXX";

mysql_connect("example.co.uk",$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO team (t_date, t_name, t_dob, t_contact, t_email, t_preferredCity, t_nightsMo, t_nightsTu, t_nightsWe, t_nightsTh, t_nightsFr, t_nightsSa, t_nightsSu, t_ownCar, t_previousWork, t_picture) VALUES ('$date', '$name','$dob','$contact','$email','$preferredCity','$nightsMo','$nightsTu','$nightsWe','$nightsTh','$nightsFr','$nightsSa','$nightsSu','$ownCar','$previousWork', '$filePath')";

// Run the query & return the result.
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check the mysql query result. If there is none, there is an error. So tell us what the error is.
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
```

Also, unrelated but worth pointing out is  `mysql_*` extensions are depreciated in PHP 5.3 & PHP 5.4. You should switch to `mysqli_*` extensions since `mysql_*` extensions with be eliminated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: Thanks for the code @JakeGould, I'll try it out tomorrow morning and see what happens. I thought `mysql_*` extensions weren't deprecated until later?

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that once I've got this sorted! Re: the error output, I got the following: `Invalid query: Unknown column 't_date' in 'field list'`

Comment: YES! That fixed it :D I added a new column for t_date and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!